# Visual Basic 2008 Mobile Project: How to Filter Data From Combo Box to DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a mobile project, and I have this:

1. A search textbox (fillby method)
2. A combobox (bound to the data)
3. A datagrid

I am able to do this:

input a search query into the textbox using the fillby method and the datagrid shows the appropriate rows.

I need help with this:

To filter the same data with a combobox.  If I use the Add Query method (fillby method) to a combobox it creates another textbox search query.  I don't want that.  I want to be able to **filter the datagrid by the combobox**.

Here is my code for the ComboBox Sub:

```
    Private Sub CityComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CityComboBox.SelectedValueChanged

    Dim RestIDShort As Short       'primary key
    Dim RestDataRow As DataRow     'complete data row of selected value
    Dim RestDataRows As DataRow()  'holding the data

    Try

        'get the restID for the selected city
        RestIDShort = Convert.ToInt16(CityComboBox.SelectedValue)

        'find the row from the table for the selected city
        RestDataRow = RestaurantEateriesDataSet.RestaurantTable.FindByRestID(RestIDShort)

        'Grab the variables here. Don't really need them.  Just to see if I can pull data.

        'NameStringShow = RestDataRow("Name")
        'FoodTypeStringShow = RestDataRow("FoodCat")
        'CityStringShow = RestDataRow("City")

        'test to see if we can write to screen
        'successfully wrote this to the screen onload but not on combobox change
        'TextBox1.Text = NameStringShow

        'retrieve the array for the selected data row
        'not sure if this is how to call when there is only one table????
         RestDataRows = RestDataRow.GetChildRows("RestaurantTable")

        'fill the datagrid with the array of selected value rows
        'I don't know how to do this part:   


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    End Sub
```

I do have a query created that I can call (if needed).  The query works when I call it in a textbox, so if there is a way to call it in a combo box, and then display the selected fields in the datagrid . . . all would be good.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub bttnFilter Click(...) Handles bttnFilter.Click
    Dim filter As String
    filter = InputBox("Enter product name, or part of it")
    ProductsBindingSource.Filter = "ProductName LIKE '%" & filter.Trim & "%'"
End Sub
```

the same is applied to combobox, use combobox1.selectedItem() in place of the filter.
its the basics of searching, it you have any other question you're welcome.

Comment: I just moved this question here as I added better clarity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466544/visual-basic-2008-mobile-project-how-to-filter-data-from-combo-box-to-datagrid